# Shell Script to generate specific columns as separate files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to print my first column and 2nd column from radius.dat and save it to rad.2.out, first column with 3rd column as rad.3.out, and so on.

However, this script doesn't seem to be working.

```
#!/bin/bash 
for i in {2..30}
do
awk '{print $1, $i}' radius.dat > 'rad.'$i'.out'
done
```

Comment: If you can, include the contents (or summary) of radius.dat in your post. Could you elavorate on 'the script doesn't seem to be working'?

Comment: Does `awk '{for (i = 2; i <= $NF; i++) { print $1, $i >> ("rad."i".out"); }'` do what you want? (Note it will not clear the output files if they already exist.)

Comment: If you will provide a sample of your `radius.dat` file, an efficient bash solution can be offered. Without knowing how the files are delimited, it is difficult to provide a true solution.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin radius.dat is a huge file with 600 columns,delimited by a space.Hence, I didn't post it in the question.

Comment: Well, is it `space delimited`, `tab delimited`, `comma separated values`? Just a hint will help :)

Comment: Any time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text, you have the wrong approach. Just use awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $i > ("rad."i".out")}' radius.dat
```

The only caveat is that it will lead to many open files, it might not be a problem if you are not on ancient `awk`.

What we are doing here is basically using an iterator and iterating through columns starting from the second and printing the first column and the iterator during each iteration to an output file using the naming convention as you desire.

#### Update (based on your comment to your question):

If you notice `too many open files` error then you can do:

```
awk '{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) { 
        print $1, $i >> ("rad."i".out"); 
        close("rad."i".out")
    }
}' file
```

Notice in the second option we use `>>` instead of `>`. This is due to the fact that we are closing the file after each iteration so we need to make sure we don't overwrite the existing files.

Comment: +1 Beautiful, even got the parenthesized generated output file name for portability!

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is quite off ... `awk` never gets the column. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for i in {2..30}; do
  awk "{print \$1, \$$i;}" radius.dat > "rad.$i.out"
done
```

Comment: It shows an awk error 
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ;

Comment: Just tried it here (Ubuntu 12.04), works perfectly. Please put "echo" in front of awk and post first line.

Comment: @imbenzene Any time you get that specific error message it means you are using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris) which should never be used. If you are on Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead. Don't use this solution though as it's the wrong way to access the value of shell variables in an awk script, see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for the right ways, and a shell loops the wrong approach anyway.